# cannot find or load main class

Tags: java, find, load, mainclass

```
import java.sql.*;

class TestingDatabase
{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            try
            {
                 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","metalgear");
                java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
                int i = input.nextInt();
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from students where sid=?");
                ps.setInt(1,i);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                rs.next();
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(2));

            }
           catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}
           catch(SQLException e){}
       }
}
```

I saved this code on desktop and compiled it using
`javac TestingDatabase.java` command.
It compiled successfully but when I entered the command
`java TestingDatabase`
it said `Error: could not find or load main class TestingDatabase`

I double checked for any spelling mistake but couldn't find one.
can anyone suggest any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Terrible code in every way.  Your immediate problem is likely to be an issue with paths.  Empty catch blocks?  You'll regret those when the code does nothing and you can't figure out why.

Comment: @azurefrog i know what it this statement means but i dont understand why i am getting this error.

Comment: @Max I Tried it. But same results.

Comment: @duffymo i didn't meant to use this code in large programs. i just wanted to test if my database connection is working properly.

Comment: try to add `public` to the declaration of your class `public class TestingDatabase`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto didn't work.

Comment: i mailed the same code to a friend and he didn't get this error. i dont understand why am i getting this?

Comment: you need to add your JDBC driver in your classpath by launching it with `java -cp /path/to/my/driver.jar TestingDatabase`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i added the driver.jar (ie ojdbc14.jar) file in both of these locations       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\ext
and
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\ext

Comment: @WePullWashney-bad habits are still bad.  Those drivers should not be in those locations.  It's not surprising that you are having issues.

Comment: -@duffymo these drivers have always been there . And my previous codes have worked fine . this particular code is showing this error. i was just brushing up the syntax before using it in my actual program.

Comment: You really need to a **CAREFULL** look at @azurefrog's duplicate page. There are a lot of solutions (**BUNCH SOLUTIONS WITH NOTES AND REASONS**) and reason there. So if you can't find yours..then we are sorry

Comment: @YoungMillie i read the soultion on that page several times before asking this question.

Comment: I don't trust that...CAREFULLY...because that is absolutely almost all of the possible causes and their suggested corresponding solutions. I strongly recommend you to revisit that page and carefully go through all the solutions **Especially the first one** else I guess you must solve this your own way.

Comment: @YoungMillie i just tried to execute my previous programs and they all showing the same error. I think there are problems in my computer.

Comment: @WePullWashney If you have already read the canonical answer, you should have mentioned that in your question.  It would save us a great deal of time to not have to go over things things you've already tried.

Comment: @azurefrog sorry.......i didn't meant to waste anyone's time. i think the problem is in my environment variables.

Comment: thnx guys ..the problem is solved. there was a mistake in my environment variable. i really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

agree with Young Millie on reviewing the list of possible causes.  when testing, i found no problem with either the code or executing it.  i used command line:

14:31:28$ javac TestingDatabase.java 
14:31:33$ java TestingDatabase
14:31:36$

my best guess is that your classpath which might be incorrect; it should include the current directory (.) at some point or not have a classpath defined at all